# Ранее рабочий проект Java перестал работать с переустановленной IntelliJ Idea из-за отсутствующих зависимостей

Tags: spring, maven

Например,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это pom.xml:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878045/errorjava-invalid-source-release-8-in-intellij-what-does-it-mean

Comment: @user419011 не дубликат, этот проект запускался без ошибок и с тех пор я его не изменял

Comment: Попробуйте File - Invalidate cache and restart (или как-то так)

Comment: @insolor не помогло

Comment: у вас стоит автоматическое обновление зависимостей?  Банальный реимпорт зависимостей пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что у вас сбились настройки maven(**.../.m2/settings.xml**, **.../.m2/repository**, попробуйте явно переопределить), проверьте:

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Maven** -> (User setting files, Local repository)